# Apache behind nginx gives out the wrong virtual host

Tags: apache, nginx

i have some sites on an apache webserver, lets say:

site1.com
site2.com
site3.com

apache is listening on 80 and 443 and every vhost is configured like that:

```
<VirtualHost site1.com:80>
    ServerName site1.com
    ServerAlias site1.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@site1.com
    DocumentRoot /data/site1

    <Directory /data/site1>
           AllowOverride All
           Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
           Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site1.com_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site1.com_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost site1.com:443>
    ServerName   site1.com
    ServerAlias  site1.com
    ServerAdmin  webmaster@site1.com
    DocumentRoot "/data/site1"
    #more ssl config ...
</VirtualHost>
```

now i configured a nginx reverse proxy on top of site1.com - so DNS was altered to point site1.com to the nginx and on nginx this config was made:

```
server {
    listen          site1.com:80;
    server_name     site1.com;
    expires 0;
    status_zone site1.com;
    if ($host !~ ^(site1.com)$ ) {
        return 444;
    }
    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ) {
        return 444;
    }
    location '/.well-known/acme-challenge' {
        root /etc/nginx/html/certbot;
    }
    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*) https://site1.com/$1;
    }
}
server {
    listen          site1.com:443 ssl;
    server_name     site1.com;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/site1.com,/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/site1.com/privkey.pem;
    expires 0;
    status_zone site1.com;
    if ($host !~ ^(site1.com)$ ) {
        return 444;
    }
    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ) {
        return 444;
    }
    location '/.well-known/acme-challenge' {
        root /etc/nginx/html/certbot;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://apache_server_IP:80;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

so nginx acts as reverse proxy and it worked fine - one day later i see the content from site2.com on site1.com

i checked if nginx sends the right host-header - in the nginx-config proxy_set_header Host $host is set - and nginx sends the right host-header (extend apache logging with %{Host}i)

so i can see requests to site1.com in the log for site2.com with an entry like this

site1.com $nginx_IP - - [07/Nov/2019:10:07:29 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 313 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"

with this LogFormat:

```
LogFormat "%{Host}i %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
```

my solution was to delete the listen:80 for site2 and site3 - now when nginx comes with a request on port 80 there is only one vhost left (site1) - the Downside: site2 and site3 are now only available over https (not a real problem but i want them to listen on 80 and redirect to 443 again)

i dont know where the problem is - is apache trying to fool me?

Answer (score 0):

after reading some more apache-docs (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) i tried the asterisks in the vhosts and now it works!

just use

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

instead of

```
<VirtualHost site1.com:80>
```

i dont want to think about this any more